# Extracting multiple fields from a JSON payload

Tags: json, jq

I have the following payload

```
[
  {
    "name": "ProductCostingBJF_v2.3.0",
    "commit": {
    },
    "protection": {
      "enabled": true,
      "required_status_checks": {
        "enforcement_level": "off",
        "contexts": []
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "master",
    "commit": {
    },
    "protection": {
      "enabled": true,
      "required_status_checks": {
        "enforcement_level": "off",
        "contexts": []
      }
    }
  }
]
```

can you help with the jq syntax to pull out and present

```
ProductCostingBJF_v2.3.0    true
master                      true
```

I got the first part ... I can get the branch name with

```
jq  -r .[].name
```

but i cannot figure how to get the enabled value.

Comment: .[].name, .[].protection.enabled    like this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following jq command:

```
jq -r '.[]| "\(.name) \(.protection.enabled)"' a.json
```

You can pipe it to `column` to get aligned output:

```
jq -r '.[]| "\(.name) \(.protection.enabled)"' a.json | column -t
```

Output:

```
ProductCostingBJF_v2.3.0  true
master                    true
```

Comment: Consider using string interpolation instead: `"\(.name) \(.protection.enabled)"`

Comment: Definitely better since it does not require to explicitly run `tostring`. I'll use that consequently from now on! Thanks for the hint!

Comment: Spot on answer - this was GREATLY appreciated and the hint on how to get on oneline was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Here is alternative syntax using joined lines (`-j`):

```
$ jq -j '.[] | .name, "\t", .protection.enabled, "\n"' payload.json 
ProductCostingBJF_v2.3.0    true
master  true
```